# How to get combo-box display values using the Data field?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2008, combobox

I have set the combo-box data to "first;second;third" in the resource editor, but when I compile the program, the combo-box is totally empty, I can't see there any items at all.

Also, how do I set which item is selected by default ? And how do I change the currently selected item programmatically ?

Comment: Are you using MFC CComboBox class to create your combo-box?

Comment: @yasouser, nope, i just created the combo-box in the visual-studio resource editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this tutorial on Win32 Combo boxes: [Introduction to Combo Boxes](http://www.functionx.com/win32/controls/combobox.htm)

If you are using MFC CComboBox class then you need to use the methods [`AddString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9y44b47%28VS.80%29.aspx) or [`InsertString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fshs3k34%28VS.80%29.aspx) to add elements in the combo box list.

Comment: Thanks for the link, seems like the SendMessage() is the only way.

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be found in this article: http://codeguru.earthweb.com/cpp/com-tech/atl/atl/print.php/c3599

The DLGINIT resource added by the resource editor is a list of messages to pass to child controls just after the dialog is created. MFC has code to do this automatically in the `ExecuteDlgInit` method, so solutions based on MFC will "just work"; everybody else will have to provide their own code for initialization. It also appears that the messages inserted by the dialog editor are based on the 16-bit Windows API and need translation for 32/64-bit Windows.

I would suggest ignoring the initialization data provided by the dialog editor and using the [CB_ADDSTRING message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775828(v=vs.85).aspx) to place the initial strings.

Some other good advice here: http://www.flounder.com/combobox.htm

Answer (score 1):

In "Data" field, enter values separated by semicolon `;` as follows:

```
line1;line2;line3
```

On initialization, each of these values will show up in a line.

This works in VS 2015, and I think as far back as VS 2008

Answer (score 0):

For setting value,you can use AddString() method mycombobox.AddString("first"); mycombobox.AddString("second"); mycombobox.AddString("third"); For setting index, you can use SetCurSel() method and set to Default value "first". mycombobox.SetCurSel(0);