# Accessing the user selected item from dropdownbox

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to access the value from the dropdownbox(ID set to `cboLang` in the Properties window) which resides in my Dialogbox using the following code:

```
int item = cboLang.GetCurSel();
if(item != CB_ERR)
{
  CString text;
  cboLang.GetLBText(item,text);
}
```

But `cboLang` is showing an error in the editor that:

> expression must have class type

Am new to C++.Net. So please don't be harsh on me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `cboLang` is the ID, then you need something like:

```
CListBox *pList = (CListBox *) GetDlgItem(cboLang);
int item = pList->GetCurSel();
if(item != CB_ERR)
{
  CString text;
  pList->GetText(item,text);
}
```

**EDIT**
On re-reading your post, it looks like you have a combo instead of a list box; in that case, the code would be:

```
CComboBox *pCombo = (CComboBox *) GetDlgItem(cboLang);
int item = pCombo->GetCurSel();
if(item != CB_ERR)
{
  CString text;
  pCombo->GetLBText(item,text);
}
```

Comment: THanks Edward (y) The error is gone now. Also found that GetLBText() is an void function and the second parameter is passed as reference! So I have corrected my post by moving that line to be next line after the declaration of the CString `text`. One thing I am having issue is, I have set the items for the dropdownbox at design time using text separated by semicolons for the `Data` property. But when the program is ran, the items won't appear in the list!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I've fixed the code. `the items won't appear in the list` --> do you mean nothing is selected or the dropdown-list is empty? if it is empty, then there's probably some code that is resetting the combo contents (I've used combo boxes with pre-filled `Data` without any problems)

Comment: I mean the dropdown is empty! :( Tried creating another comboxbox with just `a;b;c` as `Data` in properties window. At runtime, it is showing empty list!

Comment: From [this SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6203671/1850797), it looks like it works only when you use MFC to maanage the dialog box (using Class Wizard), there's also a link to code you need to use otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. I have been trying to research and exercise on it for the last 2hrs. but no success! Why C++ do it in the hardway always! ? :(