# how to add items to combobox in resouce script in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, resources

I am creating a font dialog box which consists of `font selection/styling/sizing` in C++ using the Windows API.

I added text and a combobox in my resource script, but I am confused about how to add items to the combobox and handle its click events. I searched the Internet but am unable to find the answer.

My code is

```
#include "Resource.h"
#include <windows.h>
#define IDD_DLGFIRST 101
#define IDC_SCROLLBARV                  1010
#define COMBOX1 1
#define COMBOX2 2
#define COMBOX3 3
IDD_DLGFIRST DIALOG 200, 200, 300, 200
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Font Color"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg"
BEGIN
     LTEXT "Font",10,10,15,80,20
     COMBOBOX COMBOX1,10,30,80,100, CBS_SIMPLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
     LTEXT "Font Style",11,110,15,80,20
     COMBOBOX COMBOX2,110,30,80,100, CBS_SIMPLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
     LTEXT "Font Size",11,210,15,80,20
     COMBOBOX COMBOX3,210,30,80,100, CBS_SIMPLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
END
```

Comment: This question came up in the review queue, and I can confirm that it's exceedingly difficult to find an example demonstrating how to add items to a combo box from within the resource file, despite pages and pages of documentation on this control on msdn.  Perhaps it's considered bad practice?

Comment: @zzxyz you are not finding an example because it can't be done with a resource script alone, the items can only be added in code instead. And there is plenty of documentation and examples of doing that, whether you use a resource script or not.

Comment: These resource scripts are rather limited. Not to mention weird dialog units. It would be considerably more flexible to manage window creation manually or develop own resource description format.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add items to a ComboBox via a resource script. The script can only define the ComboBox itself and its characteristics. You need to write code to handle the ComboBox items at runtime.

For instance, in your dialog's WndProc procedure, handle the [`WM_INITDIALOG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645428.aspx) message to send [`CB_ADDSTRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775828.aspx) messages to the ComboBox's `HWND`, which you can get from the Win32  [`GetDlgItem()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645481.aspx) function.

To handle clicks and other events from the ComboBox, they are sent to your dialog's WndProc in the form of [`WM_COMMAND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591.aspx) notifications, such as [`CBN_SELCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775821.aspx).

And FYI, Windows has its own built-in [Font Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646958.aspx), which you can invoke using the Win32 [`ChooseFont()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646914.aspx) function, or the MFC [`CFontDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfontdialog-class) class, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The API does not know how to take items from the resource script, you could however do like MFC and use the data element part of the CONTROL resource statement. You would then have to read the saved information during the WM_INITDIALOG handler and add the items to the combo box.

I'm not sure if the resource dialog designer is able to add such items if you aren't dealing with an MFC project.

Comment: [Here is some explanation how MFC does it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6203671/7571258)